# Contact form 7: validate button

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using the contact form 7 plugin for wordpress.
I need a fake submit button i.e. a button that does the validation check on the fields after which, if everything is ok, the user will be redirected to another url otherwise he will stay on the current page and see the input errors.
All this without sending the form data.

What can I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CF7 most of the form validation is done on the server side, so there's no way to validate a form without actually sending the form data. This is done via AJAX. You can, however, add a DOM listener that will redirect the user after that validation succeeds: https://contactform7.com/dom-events/

Answer (score 0):

set the attribute "required" in input or texarea

```
let form_element = document.querySelectorAll('.input-or-textarea');

form_element.forEach((element) => element.setAttribute('required', true));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).